# How can I use Countdown Timer in Broadcast Receiver 's Receiver Event?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created a service in which when user press power button 3 times sos service should be started. I need following requirement
When first time it receive a capture count is equal to 1.
When count=1 timer should be start for 1 minute . In that 1 minute when count =3 my sos service should be started. How to do this?
I have tried this.

```
 public void onReceive(Context paramAnonymousContext, Intent paramAnonymousIntent) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            String str = String.valueOf(time);
            str = str.substring(0,9);
            time = Long.parseLong(str);

            Long timestamp = pref.getLong("timestamp",0);
            int counter = pref.getInt("counter",0);
            if(timestamp != 0){
                if(time == timestamp){
                    counter++;
                    if(counter == 3){
                        editor.putInt("counter",0);
                        editor.putString("SOS","SOS OFF");
                        editor.putInt("SOS_Flag",0);    //for power button
                        Log.e("power button counter",String.valueOf(counter));
                        startService(new Intent(paramAnonymousContext, SosService.class));
                    }else{
                        editor.putInt("counter",counter);
                        editor.putLong("timestamp",time);
                    }
                }else{
                    editor.putLong("timestamp",time);
                    editor.putInt("counter",counter);
                }
            }else{
                editor.putLong("timestamp",time);
                editor.putInt("counter",counter);
            }
            editor.apply();
```

Comment: What happening using current code?

Comment: current code stores count whenever it presses power button

Answer (score 1):

To start a timer, you can use something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //send SOS if counter == 3
                    }
                }, 60000);
```

Just start this code on `counter == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

why is there a need of saving timestamps? Following will start your service if power button clicked for 3 times. and after 3 time click, it will initialize counter to 0. Let me know in comments if anything is missing.

```
int powerBtnClick = pref.getLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER", 0);
powerBtnClick++;
editor.putLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER",powerBtnClick);
editor.appy(); //update power btn counter at each receive

if(powerBtnClick==3){
    startService(new Intent(context, SosService.class));
}
else if(powerbtnCLick > 3){
        editor.putLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER",0);//init to zero if more than 3
        editor.appy();
        //do whatever   
    }
}
```

**Updated answer:**

```
        int powerBtnClick = pref.getLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER", 0);
        powerBtnClick++;
        editor.putLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER",powerBtnClick);
        editor.appy(); //update power btn counter at each receive

        if(powerBtnClick==1){ // save start time at first click
            long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            editor.putLong("START_TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
            editor.appy();
        }

        if(powerBtnClick==3){ //save end time at last click
            long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            editor.putLong("END_TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
            editor.appy();
        }

        long timeDiff = pref.getLong("END_TIMESTAMP", 0) - pref.getLong("START_TIMESTAMP", 0);
        long oneMinute = 60*1000;


        if(powerBtnClick==3 && timeDiff < oneMinute){ //check if 3 clicks are consecutive within one minute.
            startService(new Intent(context, SosService.class));
        }
        else if(powerbtnCLick > 3){
            editor.putLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER",0);//init to zero if more than 3
            editor.appy();
            //do whatever
        }
```

**More concise :**

```
 int powerBtnClick = pref.getLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER", 0);
    powerBtnClick++;
    editor.putLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER",powerBtnClick);
    editor.appy(); //update power btn counter at each receive


    switch(powerBtnClick){
        case 1:
            long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            editor.putLong("START_TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
            editor.appy();
            break;

        case2: 
            break;

        case 3:
            long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            editor.putLong("END_TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
            editor.appy();

            long timeDiff = pref.getLong("END_TIMESTAMP", 0) - pref.getLong("START_TIMESTAMP", 0);
            long oneMinute = 60*1000;
            if(timeDiff < oneMinute){ break; }

            startService(new Intent(context, SosService.class));

            break;

        case default:
                editor.putLong("KEY_POWER_BTN_COUNTER",0);//init to zero if more than 3
                editor.appy();
                 break;
                //do whatever



    }
```

Comment: If I apply this code shared preference stored power button count at any time suppose someone click on power button at 12.05 pm counter =1 suppose one again click power button at 12.25 pm it again increment by 1 so counter =2.. But I need like this if one press Power button continuously 3 time within 1 minutes then and then counter should be increment.. What to do?